# Autocomplete using sqlite using jQuery and Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, sqlite, cordova

How I will call and create autocomplete search in jQuery which get the data from SQlite database using Cordova 3.2?

After 3 char it should start searching the data from database (SQLite).

HTML5

```
<div>
  <input id="valueEnter" onInput="clickfunc();"/>
</div>
```

Jquery:-

```
function clickfunc(){
  //here i m calling database but it is not working
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer

Html5

```
<div class="e-input-cell">
  <input id="valueEnter" oninput="clickfunc(this)" />
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#valueEnter" id="valueId"></ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:-

```
function clickfunc(object) {
$("#valueId").empty();
var valueId= "";
var valueIdName= $("#valueEnter").val();
if (valueIdName.length > 2) {
    var select = '%' + valueIdName+ '%';
    db.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT NAME FROM Tablename WHERE NAME LIKE "' + valueIdName+ '";', [],
            function (transaction, results) {
                if (results != null && results.rows != null) {
                    if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                            var code = results.rows.item(i).NAME;
                            valueId+= '<li data-filtertext="' + code + '"><a href="#">' + code + '</a></li>'
                        }
                        $("#valueId").append(valueId).selectmenu('refresh');
                    } 
                }
            });
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this technology, but this SQL statement looks like it has a SQL injection vulnerability in it. If `valueIdName` is unfiltered user input, and the database is remote, a user may be able to run SQL statements of their own choosing against this database.